# Why is MongoDb not mapping Id?

Tags: c#, mongodb, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IChartDefinitionBasic
{
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
    string Id { get; }
    IMetricDefinition MetricDefinition { get; }
}
```

... as well as a simple implementation for testing purposes:

```
    class DummyDefinitionBasic : IChartDefinitionBasic
    {
        internal DummyDefinitionBasic(string metricName)
        {
            MetricDefinition = new DummyMetricDefinition(metricName);
            Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
        }

        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
        public string Id { get; private set; }
        public IMetricDefinition MetricDefinition { get; private set; }
    }
```

The test method below throws an exception when it reaches the `_service.Delete(_dto)` line ("Unable to determine the serialization information for c => c.Id"):

```
[TestClass]
public class MongoChartServiceTest
{
    private readonly MongoChartService _service = new MongoChartService();
    private readonly IChartDefinitionBasic _dto = DummyDefinitionGenerator.GetDummyDefinitionBasic();

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("MongoService")]
    public void MongoChartService_CRD_ExecutesSuccessfully()
    {
        _service.Create(_dto);
        IChartDefinitionBasic dto = null;
        while (dto == null)
        {
            var dtos = _service.GetAllCharts();
            dto = dtos.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == _dto.Id);
        }
        _service.Delete(_dto);
        while (dto != null)
        {
            var dtos = _service.GetAllCharts();
            dto = dtos.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == _dto.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

The delete method implementation is as follows:

```
    public async void Delete(IChartDefinitionBasic instance)
    {
        var builder = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<IChartDefinitionBasic>();
        var filter = builder.Eq(c => c.Id, instance.Id);
        await _collection.DeleteOneAsync(filter);
    }
```

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531990/unable-to-determine-the-serialization-information-for-i-i-id-using-interfaces), but it doesn't seem to help.  Instead of c => c.Id, I substituted "Id", but now the test never exits; in any case, I'd prefer to use the Expression since it's cleaner (I'm stuck on C# 5.0 for the time being).  Can someone explain why this doesn't work and what is necessary to fix it?

Comment: Try to change type of your id from `string` to `ObjectId`. Mongo tries to map it as ObjectId, not as string

Comment: No dice - I converted from `string` to `ObjectId` in my `IChartDefinitionBasic` interface but still end up with the same error when I cross `_collection.DeleteOneAsync`.  It is possible to work against interfaces with MongoDb, yes?

Comment: I think no, There are some problems with interfaces in mongo. As I know you should work only with objects itself. Mongo works with objects that is directly representing its documents. If you really si much want it, you can work with base class (but I guess it can not be abstract), but you will have to tell mongo about it

Comment: Have you tried adding the attribute `[BsonElement("_id")]`?

Comment: @itsme86: Just tried it, no luck.  I do get an entry in the dB with a randomly generated id (with or without the 'BsonElement').

Comment: @Andrew: It does work with an abstract base class and virtual members.  Do you know if the Mongo limitations with interfaces are a bug or part of the design intent?  I'm a noob with this so I could just be completely missing the point.

Comment: @ket: Regarding the interfaces - this is design implementation. About abstract base classes - maybe, unfortunately do not know exactly. I know that you have to tell Mongo about your inheritance. Moreover, you should specify mongo attribute for each of your child class in your parent class, and this is not very comfortable for me. Also as i know additional parse problems could be